# Automated testing for transient keyword

Tags: apex, unit-test

one of our business requirements is that the data in a certain field in a form is not persisted as the user navigates different objects in salesforce.

Without getting into too much detail, we have been able to implement this business requirement by adding the **transient** keyword to the field.

The field now looks like this:

```
public transient String Note { get; set; }
```

Given that this has now become a requirement, we want to automate the testing of the acceptance criteria to avoid a regression in the future (for instance, a developer removing the transient keyword, etc).

Are there any ways to automatically test this? Could I use Reflection or describe to read that field and know whether it's transient? Is there some kind of Unit Test pattern that would allow me to test that a field is essentially transient and not transmitted in the viewstate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [`transient`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) field won't be serialized. Either to viewstate or to JSON. Viewstate is a bit difficult in a test context, but JSON isn't.

Use [JSON.serialise(object)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) to create a string representation and then assert that is doesn't contain your transient property.

E.g.

```
public class SomeController {
    public transient String Note { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

SomeController sc = new SomeController();
sc.Foo = 'Bar';
sc.Note = 'Shhh!';
string jsonSc = JSON.serialize(sc);
System.debug(jsonSc);
System.assert(jsonSc.contains(sc.Foo));
System.assert(!jsonSc.contains(sc.Note));
```

Comment: very crafty Daniel!

Comment: Daniel -- this is pretty cool; have you got any rules of thumb/algos to infer from the JSON size anything about the viewstate size?  I would guess not as viewstate includes VF components unknown to the apex side.  The above verifies that `transient` isn't inadvertently removed but doesn't test to see if new non-transient properties are added that could blow viewstate. We really need a PageReference method `getViewStateSize()`

Comment: @cropredy I haven't tested to see what the relationship between JSON size and viewstate size is. It would be an interesting experiment to run. If the serialization used by the viewstate differs significantly from JSON there might not be much of a correlation. The component tree and internal housekeeping parts of the viewstate would make it hard to estimate the size by object structure alone.

Comment: Where in code could you use a getViewStateSize() method? The view state isn't created until [step 4 in the order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm) if an apex:form is present. By that state all the controller code would have executed.

Comment: Good point, perhaps the method would work after `Test.stopTest()`; I'm sort of astral-projecting here.  I adapted your answer here and used it in a testmethod for regression testing viewstate growth. See http://cropredysfdc.com/2016/04/30/testing-viewstate-in-apex-testmethods/ - be curious what you think.