# Apex @RestResource returning result inner class exposes private attributes

Tags: restresource, inner-class, private

Any simple @RestResource may return results in the form of an instance of an inner class.
I expect any private attribute of the inner class to stay exposed only to the inner class, thus not be streamed out into the @RestResource results.
However, private fields are also returned.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping('/mywebservice/v1/*)
global without sharing class MyWebservice_V1 {

    global class Result {
        String data = 'abc';
        private Boolean isClient = FALSE;
    }

    @HttpGet
    global static Result doGet() {
        return new Result();
    }
}

// Returns the following :
// {
//     "data" : "abc",
//     "isClient" : true
// }

// Expected result :
// {
//     "data" : "abc",
// }
```

How can I remove private fields from the streamed @RestResource returned result ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automated testing for transient keyword](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47451/automated-testing-for-transient-keyword)

Comment: I think the link provided above answers this question. But the question itself is different than the one asked here. I wouldn't want to close this question as a Dupe, perhaps we can copy the relevant parts here so there is a proper answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) do (kind of) call this out: (my emphasis)

> You can use user-defined types for parameters in your Apex REST methods. Apex REST deserializes request data into `public`, **`private`**, or `global` class member variables of the user-defined type, unless the variable is declared as `static` or `transient`.

Their example is related to deserialization, but the inverse is also true for serialization. This is implied in the docs with the line:

> Apex REST uses similar serialization logic for the response. An Apex method with a non-void return type will have the return value serialized into RestResponse.responseBody.

You will need to make the private members [`transient`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) if you don't want them exposed through the API.

Comment: Ah, "transient" : good idea, and think that is the answer. I tried "private" before posting this, but it was not sufficient.